# Comments don't onebox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

[image]

Here is the problem. For some reason Arqade comments don't onebox (I tried with `http` and `https`)

I tried to onebox the comment `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam/#comment357863_257114` (The chat message is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33480047#33480047))

Comment: That one doesn't work but others are just fine... not all of Arqade's comments fail to onebox.

Comment: @Catija Huh, that's weird

Comment: That question seems to be the issue.  Comments on other questions work fine... that one doesn't. Not sure why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regex, it's always the regex. Seriously now, the reason is a rogue trailing slash you have in the URL, which is not supposed to be there.

If you browse to the [ordinary question URL](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam) which is `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam` the comment links will onebox just fine, e.g. `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam#comment357863_257114`.

However, if somehow you end up [adding a slash after the title in the url](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam/), which is `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257112/how-do-i-change-my-name-on-steam/`, everything still appears fine however the comment links become what you described and indeed won't onebox.

The bug is whatever gave you that URL, if it was internal SE link and not added manually by someone.

Onebox can of course remove it as well, but not sure if it's worth the efforts.

Comment: When I was testing, I got the link in the normal way - right click - copy link. So, directly from the date stamp. Not sure why this question has the issue. Other comments on that question do the same thing.

Comment: @Catija because you copied the link provided by the OP here (or clicked the link in chat), which already got the slash. Ordinary link, e.g. the question title on arqade, is fine and doesn't have the slash.

Comment: Ah. I see. Hmmm.

Comment: @Catija yeah... also looked in [search results](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+do+I+change+my+name+on+Steam), link there is fine. Dunno where that slash came from, maybe some fancy userscript someone got, always adding slashes... or maybe someone was just messing around.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you should naturally end up with trailing slashes like that at any point, but I know I've ended up with them after instinctively cleaning `286893#286893` from a the end of URL like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286892/comments-dont-onebox/286893#286893`.

For people like us, oneboxing of comment URLs with such trailing slashes is now supported.